# Where I can get information to make the WidgetsBindingObserver works again?

Tags: flutter

After upgrading to Flutter 0.7.3 channel beta (Dart 2.1.0-dev.1.0.flutter-ccb16f7282) the WidgetsBindingObserver is not working.

It worked before and after login if AppLifecycleState paused, inactive or suspended it returns to main page. But seems it doesnt work with new update. My question is where I can get information to see how to make the WidgetsBindingObserver works again.

```
// Statefull HomePage
class PersonalLoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const PersonalLoginPage({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _PersonalLoginPageState createState() => new _PersonalLoginPageState();
}

class _PersonalLoginPageState extends State<PersonalLoginPage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  AppLifecycleState _appLifecycleState;
  bool _appStatePause;


  // TODO: initState function
  @override
  void initState() {
    print("initState Starting Now .......................");
    super.initState();
    authenticateUser();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    Timer _timer;
    setState(() {
      _appLifecycleState = state;
      if (_appLifecycleState == AppLifecycleState.paused ||
          _appLifecycleState == AppLifecycleState.inactive ||
          _appLifecycleState == AppLifecycleState.suspending) {
        _appStatePause = true;
        print("New Timer Starting Now .......................");
        _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 60), _callback);
      } else {
        _appStatePause = false;
      }
    });
  }

  void _callback(_timer) {
    if (_appStatePause == true) {
      print("Timer Finished without cancel...................");
      setState(() {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          SlideRightRoute(widget: MyApp()),
        );
      });
    } else {
      _timer.cancel();
      print("Timer cancel now................................");
    }
  }

  // TODO: authenticateUser function
  Future authenticateUser() async {
    ……
    ……
    ……

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  // TODO: main build Widget
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
         body: new Center(
            child: new Text(“Hello World”)
        )
    );
  }
```

Comment: Check the flutter github issues tracker. If it is a bug you should post there.

Comment: @Serl, thanks I will do that